# seeder for getter/setter in sequelize mysql

Tags: sequelize.js, migration, seed, sequelize-cli

hy,
for sequelize and from what I've seen here there's no Datatypes Array for mysql (it's only available for postgres). A workaround consists in using getters/setters in the migration files as this :

```
favColors: {
type: Sequelize.STRING,
allowNull: false,
get() {
    return this.getDataValue('favColors').split(';')
},
set(val) {
   this.setDataValue('favColors',val.join(';'));
},
```

}

My question is how about the seeders file ?
Here are my migration and seeder files. Any idea how to get the likers and dislikers array in the seeder file?

migration file for users:

```
    'use strict';

module.exports = {
    up: async(queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        await queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            firstName: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            familyName: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            email: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            password: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            role: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            photoUrl: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            createdAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATE
            },
            updatedAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATE
            }
        });
    },
    down: async(queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        await queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
    }
};
```

seeder file for users:

```
'use strict';

const faker = require('faker');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = {
    up: async(queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        let users = [];
        let roles = ['ADMIN', 'MODER', 'BASIC'];

        for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            let r = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
            let pwdHashed = await bcrypt.hash(r, 10);
            //let userRole = roles[(Math.random() * roles.length) | 0];
            let userRole = roles[Math.floor(Math.random() * roles.length)];
            users.push({
                firstName: faker.name.firstName(),
                familyName: faker.name.lastName(),
                email: faker.internet.email(),
                password: pwdHashed,
                role: userRole,
                photoUrl: faker.image.avatar(),
                createdAt: new Date(),
                updatedAt: new Date()
            });
        };
        await queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', users, {})
    },

    down: async(queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        await queryInterface.bulkDelete('Users', null, {});
    }
};
```

migration file for posts:

```
    'use strict';
module.exports = {
    up: async(queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        await queryInterface.createTable('Posts', {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            posterId: {
                type: Sequelize.UUID,
                referes: {
                    model: "Users",
                    key: "id"
                }
            },
            title: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            content: {
                type: Sequelize.TEXT
            },
            imageUrl: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            videoUrl: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            likers: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                get() {
                    return this.getDataValue('likers').split(';')
                },
                set(val) {
                    this.setDataValue('likers', val.join(';'));
                },
                required: true
            },
            dislikers: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                get() {
                    return this.getDataValue('dislikers');
                },
                set(val) {
                    this.setDataValue('dislikers', dislikers.push(val));
                },
                required: true
            },
            likes: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                default: 0
            },
            dislikes: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                default: 0
            },
            createdAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATE
            },
            updatedAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATE
            }
        });
    },
    down: async(queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        await queryInterface.dropTable('Posts');
    }
};
```

seeder file for posts:

```
'use strict';
const faker = require('faker');

module.exports = {
    up: async(queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        let posts = [];
        let fakeLikersDislikers = [];
        
        for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            posts.push({
                posterId: faker.datatype.uuid(),
                title: faker.lorem.sentence(),
                content: faker.lorem.sentence(),
                imageUrl: faker.image.city(),
                videoURL: faker.image.nature(),
                //videoURL: `${faker.image.nature()}?random=${Date.now()}`,


                likers: fakeLikersDislikers.push(faker.name.findName()),
                dislikers: fakeLikersDislikers.push(faker.name.findName()),
                likes: faker.datatype.number(),
                dislikes: faker.datatype.number(),
                createdAt: new Date(),
                updatedAt: new Date(),
            });
        };
        await queryInterface.bulkInsert('Posts', posts, {})
    },

    down: async(queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        await queryInterface.bulkDelete('Posts', null, {});
    }
};
```

Comment: the code above gives reult, my db is fullfilled but with likers and dislikers numbre not an array. Otherwise when I use postman to create a new post it gives me an error: "(node:6148) 
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

Comment: After several attemps I've finally managed to send Postman request but still the problem with likers/dislikers. I don't get an array only a numbre

Comment: nobody had an idea? at least just how to make seeders for properties made with get/set in the migration files?